# Change styled image through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a style specified in the head of my document. I specify the background image on a division but later on a need to change it if the user clicks on a link but everything I've tried to do refuses to work.

```
<style type="text/css">
            /*Some CSS*/
            .large {
                background: url('/images/artwork1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
</style.

<div class="large"></div>
<img id="main_image" alt="Image"/>
<img onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('main_image').sr‌​c='/images/artwork2.‌​jpg'; $('.large').css({'background-image':'url(/images/artwork2.jp‌​g)';" alt="Change Image"/>
```

I tried taking the background image out of the style but clicking on a link didn't change it. I've tried JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Please post your html as well :)

Comment: _"but everything I've tried to do refuses to work"_ – We do not see anything in provided question :(

Comment: Sticking the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) `javascript:` at the front of your onclick function is pointless. There is no loop to label. It does not declare that you are writing code in JavaScript.

Comment: `<img onclick` — Images are not designed to be interactive elements. Using one as a button introduces a number of accessibility issues. Use a button instead. `<button type="button" onclick="..."><img ...></button>`.  (and don't neglect the `alt` attribute)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> large
> ```

This is a **type** selector, it matches `<large>` elements.

A class selector begins with a `.`

```
$('.large').css({'background-image':'url(/images/artwork2.jpg)';
```

Comment: Can I mix JavaScript and jQuery into the same onclick?

Comment: Eh? jQuery is a JavaScript library. i.e. it is nothing more than "JavaScript functions that other people wrote".

Comment: This the whole onclick statement.
                                                         <img onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('main_image').src='/images/artwork2.jpg'; $('.large').css({'background-image':'url(/images/artwork2.jpg)';"
The first bit used to work by now none of it works.

Comment: Since there is no `main_image` element, you try to access the `src` property of `null`, throw an exception and the script stops.

Comment: I had used the main_image element but I didn't include that in the code I posted. I was able to change it until I added the jQuery.

Comment: Well, that's a different problem to the one you originally asked about. You should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [mcve] for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code under click event

```
var element = document.querySelector(".large");

element.style.background = "url('/images/artwork1.jpg') no-repeat;
}";
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, I think  it may have had something to do with all the nested quotes.